# Gráfico de Machine Learning

Tags: python, aprendizagem-de-máquina, gráfico, machine-learning

Estou com um problema para gerar um gráfico usando Python - Machine Learning - modelo Naive Bayes - seria plotar um F1 (score) para os diferentes valores de K, abaixo temos o classificador que me dá as seguintes saídas:

> Mean Accuracy: 0.896551724138, Mean Precision: 0.63, Mean Recall: 0.425, Mean f1: 0.486031746032.

Classificador Naive Bayes

```
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('selector', SelectKBest()),
    ('reducer', PCA(random_state=42)),
    ('classifier', GaussianNB())
])

param_grid = {
'scaler': SCALER,
'selector__k': SELECTOR__K,
'reducer__n_components': REDUCER__N_COMPONENTS
}

# sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit
gnb_grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, scoring='f1', cv=sss)

evaluate_model(gnb_grid, X, y, sss)

test_classifier(gnb_grid.best_estimator_, my_dataset, features_list)
```

Independente dos dados que utilizei eu gostaria de gerar um gráfico com o y = f1 score (cross validation) e x = K Best Features, o código abaixo que tentei contém erro e só me mostra o gráfico mas os dados não aparecem.

```
gnb_grid = []
# Plot number of features VS. cross-validation scores
plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("K Best Features")
plt.ylabel("f1 score (cross validation)")
plt.plot(gnb_grid, k_features)
plt.show()
```

Preciso gerar um como este da foto. Já agradeço pelas ajudas que chegarem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Parece que essa pergunta apenas tem relação tangencial com machine-learning. A sua dificuldade na verdade é como gerar um gráfico em Python (tanto que a resposta que vc tem faz exatamente isso). Sugiro editar pra deixar mais claro e remover as tags de aprendizagem de máquina.

Answer (score 5):

[[TL;DR]](https://anaconda.org/sidon/plot-exemple1)
Sem os dados originais fica dificil ter certeza que não seja com eles, por isso criei dados randomicos para fazer testes com o codigo que vc apresenta e o grafico foi plotado com sucesso, veja:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

f1_score = np.random.normal(loc=0.325, scale=0.25, size=50)
f1_score = f1_score[(f1_score > 0) & (f1_score < 1)]
f1_score.sort()

k_features = np.arange(len(f1_score))

plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("K Best Features")
plt.ylabel("f1 score (cross validation)")
plt.plot(k_features, f1_score)
plt.show()
```

Resultado:

[image: Plot dos dados]

[Baixe o demo em um jupyter notebook.](https://anaconda.org/sidon/plot-exemple1)

Comment: Agradeço ao Sidon por ter feito um gráfico que de fato funcionou, demorei pra responder pois eu achei que não teria resposta alguma. Agradeço mesmo. Att.